# Update nib to newest version xcode 5

Tags: xcode5, nib

I just updated to xcode 5 and when firing up my project it asked if I wanted to update the nib-file. 
Well I just said no, but now I want to, but I can not find the option anywhere. 
Maybe I am slow because it is friday, I dont know, please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goto the nib file under utilities pane ***Interface builder document***, change ***Opens in*** to ***Default(5.0)***
[image]

Remember

> This will enable editing using the iOS 7 appearance and new auto layout workflows. **This file will no longer be editable in Xcode 4.x.**

Comment: Thank you, apparently I was friday blind